# Typescript: generic interface for creating object containing options and a selection

Tags: typescript

I am trying to create a generic option type/interface which will be used to create specific option types. This generic type/interface takes a set of options as input. The parameter `value` contains the current selection, and `options` contains all the options. The parameter `value` should only be allowed to hold strings contained in `options` and `options` should be defined from the list of options defined externally.

This is my current progress:

```
export type GenericListOfOptions<list> = {
    type: 'list',
    name: string,
    value: list,
    options: Array<list>, // I am not sure if this is right...
}

// Here i define my options:
const these_options = ['yes', 'no', 'maybe'] as const;

// Here i define a specific option type from the
// generic option type. This specific option type is
// defined from the 'these_options' constant.
type MySpecificOptions = GenericListOfOptions<typeof these_options[number]>

// Here i use the type to create an option object.
let my_options: MySpecificOptions = {
    type: 'list',
    name: 'am i going to the gym?',
    value: 'no',
    options: these_options, // Here is an error relating readonly properties...
    // 'options' should be equal to ['yes', 'no', 'maybe'].
    // I preferrably want to reuse the 'these_options' array to define the 'options' parameter.
}
```

The error given is:

```
The type 'readonly ["yes", "no", "maybe"]' is 'readonly' and cannot be assigned to the mutable type '("yes" | "no" | "maybe")[]'.ts(4104)
interfaces.ts(137, 5): The expected type comes from property 'options' which is declared here on type 'MySpecificOptions '
```

But maybe there are other more general errors of this idea, so any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Aside on naming conventions: it is not conventional to use a lowercase word like `list` as a generic type parameter.  More conventional is a single uppercase letter like `L` or if you must use a word then it should be in UpperPascalCase like `List`.  I'd recommend `L` or even `T` here (because I don't see why the type parameter is "list"-like in any way, and `T` is the default for "arbitrary type parameter name").  Please consider changing this.

Comment: If you don't need to mutate the `options` property, then write `ReadonlyArray<T>` instead of `Array<T>`, as shown [here](https://tsplay.dev/mqkYkw).  Does that meet your needs? If so I could write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: That worked! Did not find ReadonlyArray<T> when i searched for a solution, so thank you alot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you initialized `these_options` as

```
const these_options = ['yes', 'no', 'maybe'] as const;
// const these_options: readonly ["yes", "no", "maybe"]
```

you used a [`const` assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#const-assertions), presumably so the compiler would remember that the elements consist of the string [literal types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#literal-types) `"yes"`, `"no"`, and `"maybe"`.  But it also has the effect of making `these_options` have a [*`readonly`* tuple type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#readonly-tuples), which is a subtype of [the `ReadonlyArray` type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#the-readonlyarray-type).  It is not known to have the *mutating* methods of [the `Array` type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#the-array-type), like [the `push()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) or [the `splice()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice), etc.  `ReadonlyArray<T>` is therefore *wider* than `Array<T>`.  That means `Array<T>` is assignable to `ReadonlyArray<T>` but not vice versa.

---

So given the definition of `GenericListOfOptions<T>` as

```
type GenericListOfOptions<T> = {
    type: 'list',
    name: string,
    value: T,
    options: Array<T>, 
}
```

then of course this will be a problem:

```
let my_options: MySpecificOptions = {
    type: 'list',
    name: 'am i going to the gym?',
    value: 'no',
    options: these_options // error
}
```

because the `options` property must be an `Array<"yes" | "no" | "maybe">`, but `these_options` is only known to be a `ReadonlyArray<"yes" | "no" | "maybe">`.

---

Presumably you don't actually intend to mutate the contents of the `options` property of `GenericListOfOptions<T>`.  If so, then the simplest solution is to widen the `options` property type to `ReadonlyArray<T>`:

```
type GenericListOfOptions<T> = {
    type: 'list',
    name: string,
    value: T,
    options: ReadonlyArray<T>, // change
}

let my_options: MySpecificOptions = {
    type: 'list',
    name: 'am i going to the gym?',
    value: 'no',
    options: these_options // okay
}
```

---

On the other hand, if you *do* want to mutate `these_options`, and you *do* need `Array<T>` instead of `Readonly<T>`, then you could do an [array spread](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax#spread_in_array_literals) to copy the `const`-asserted tuple into a mutable array:

```
const these_options = [...['yes', 'no', 'maybe'] as const];
// const these_options: ("yes" | "no" | "maybe")[]
```

And then you could leave `GenericListOfOptions<T>` alone.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/HYQwtgpgzgDiDGEAEAlCIAmB7YAbAnkgN4BQJSFSEAHjFgE4AuSj+MyA4hMBPQJbwAMnyiMA8gDMxMRnxxQAPABUAfEgC8xcpR2t2ALiQByXCMZGANNp0VQkQ6P7AA5lZuUAbiFwBXCIaU3dyQsGTlgKEM0TBwCAEF6ehB8ZRUgigBfMh14eWZGAAtoCAB9UNl5DSQAbSN8aEtjYCxGozBkgCMIIwBdJBAoJFyIxgBuayQAekmhvJYiqFLy8MikenRsPEJqgCJ6qB2LJB3mw+P2-C6dnom9ZABZfABldng+CQFpCoiqrh5+IRmSRfFYKO5YCTzYplMLyarAHxgLr0HoqbKUXAQZhgfAw76rR4vCBvD7wEGVTSkYIsNj+YymUSWCY6Ox0ozgJB8JDOLB8FwsLBQ7n4MAAfiZ1K8vjZzQlwWW8kMhWhCoiEyyJA1rNgCAePkYIA6mK0OhodCYNPYSD+vAEwlEwNhEVSVSpwTuhhMZjl7lZDkYTlczM83j8AXSNlVqwSSRSqgjGpyc2VizxKyq1QAdNnavtWrKjm1Ot0+gNZiMeuMdNNy6Ioamo4YABR7aA7JAAH2Op0752LOwAlNUbrpaUhCa93p8nYNNDaAfbxFIZ2DaRD60sZ-DEcjUeiKJjsbjG+PnpPSeSfpTgxQPfTvRGWeA2RyuTy+c4BULnCLxY+Q9KnoFjeIQzkqCybvi6pkBkQA)

Comment: Thank you also for the mutable array solution, as of now i only need the readonly array, but the mutable array might later come in handy, so thank you!